# MYSQL view without using variables

Tags: mysql, variables, view

i want to convert this query into a view. I need to eliminate use of variables. The SQL code is like this:

```
SET @runningTotal = 0;
SELECT
    feescollected.DatePaid,  feescollected.TermPaidFor,                                                                                                                            
    feescollected.FeesPaid,
 @runningTotal := @runningTotal + feescollected.FeesPaid AS runningTotal
FROM  feescollected;
```

expected output:

```
DatePaid    TermPaidFor     FeesPaid    runningTotal 
----------------------------------------------------    
2014-02-06  I               150000      150000
2014-03-24  I               70000       220000
2014-04-08  I               80000       300000
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
SELECT
    feescollected.DatePaid,  feescollected.TermPaidFor,                                                                                                                            
    feescollected.FeesPaid,
 (feescollected.FeesPaid + 0) AS runningTotal
FROM  feescollected;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to calculate the total based on the date

```
SELECT
    a.DatePaid,
    a.TermPaidFor,                                                                                                                            
    a.FeesPaid,
(select  sum(b.FeesPaid) from feescollected b where a.DatePaid >= b.DatePaid) AS runningTotal
FROM  feescollected a
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cee32/10)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though once i added more data & columns the results go wrong. I think i need to learn how sub-queries flow of execution.